# Is there a way to display a GIF image in Colab R Kernel?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, gif, choropleth, gganimate

I have created a gif made of choropleths in Colab using the R Kernel.

The code is:

```
GIF <- mapa_provincias %>%

  ggplot() + #Iniciamos ggplot2 sin añadir nada

  geom_sf(aes(fill = Tasa_Paro/100), color= "black", size = 0.2) +  #fill: variable que queremos representar en el mapa (dividimos entre 100, porque la opción scales::percent que cierra este bloque, multiplica por 100)
  
  geom_sf(data = can_box) + #Añadimos la caja que contiene las islas Canarias

  transition_states(Periodo, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1, wrap=TRUE) +

  labs( title = "Tasa de paro por provincias ({closest_state})", #Títulos y subtítulos
        subtitle = "(%)",
        caption = "Fuente: INE",
        fill = "") + #Título de la leyenda

  xlab("Longitud") + ylab("Latitud") + #Nombres de los ejes

  theme_minimal() + #Tema de fondo (existen diferentes temas de fondo en ggplot2)
  
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),     #Línea de recuadro del mapa
    axis.text = element_blank(),     #Hemos quitado la información de latitud y longitud porque no tenía mucho sentido, al haber movido las Canarias
    axis.title = element_blank(),    #Si queremos que aparezcan los nombres de los ejes, debemos comentar esta línea
    #axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    #plot.background = element_rect(fill = "snow", color = NA), #Color de fondo panel (lo que queda fuera del contorno del mapa) Si queremos que sea del mismo color que el fondo del mapa, quitar la #
    panel.background = element_rect(fill= "aliceblue", color = NA),  #Color de fondo mapa 
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0),            #Tamaño de los títulos
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0),
    plot.caption = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 1),
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"), #Tamaño de la leyenda 
    #legend.title = element_text(color = "grey40", size = 15),
    legend.text = element_text(color = "grey40", size = 10, hjust = 0), #Tamaño texto de la leyenda
    #legend.position = c(0.93, 0.3), #Posición de la leyenda: primer parámetro: cuanto más cercano a 1, más a la derecha; segundo parámetro: cuando más cercano a 1, más arriba.
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,2,0.5,1), "cm")) + #Tamaño de los márgenes en cm

  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightyellow", high = "firebrick1", labels = scales::percent) #Escala de colores de la leyenda

# animate it
GIF <- animate(GIF,
        width = 800, height = 800,
        nframes = 480, fps = 4)

anim_save("Gif_Tasa_Paro_desde_2002.gif", GIF)
```

The GIF is correctly created but I'm not able to show it on Colab. However, I can visualizate it if I downloaded it.

Is there a way to display a GIF image in Colab R Kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a solution I have discovered this one [thanks to a `IRdisplay` developer](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/532#issuecomment-1153847230):

```
install.packages("IRdisplay")
library(IRdisplay)

display_gif <- function(raw){
    contents <- base64enc::base64encode(raw)
    tag <- '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,%s">'
    IRdisplay::display_html(sprintf(tag, contents))
}

display_gif(GIF)
```